# Find the inverse of a function like $f(t,x,y)=(\frac{x}{t+1},\frac{y}{t+1})$

Tags: calculus, geometry, inverse, inverse-function

How would I find the inverse of a function like $f(t,x,y)=(\frac{x}{t+1},\frac{y}{t+1})$? The usual trick with replacing x and y and than solving for y doesn't really work here does it?

$(t,x,y)\in \Bbb H^2$

I'd prefer a hint over a full answer, so I can try to find the final solution myself.

Comment: you are mapping three variables to two. Inverting this would mean you need to reconstruct three numbers, given only two. But that is not possible. Thats the intuitive reason why such a function can not be invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is not invertible because it is not injective; for example:

$$f(0,1,1)=f(1,2,2)=... =(1,1,1)$$

Comment: It's from hyperbolic geometry, so t>0, sorry forgot to mention that. And the previous question was to prove that is a bijective function, so it is injective.

Comment: I don't think it's a question of positivity because we also have $f(1,2,2)=f(2,3,3)=... f(t,t+1,t+1)$ for any $t$. So it is far from being injective. *But* may be, you consider "homogeneous" (or projective) coordinates, i.e.,  "up" to a common factor, I mean by that  that you maybe consider (t,x,y) as being equivalent to (kt,ky,ky) or something like that ?

Comment: Sure it's bijective? Seems like $f(2u,2v,1)=f(3u,3v,2)=(u,v)$

Comment: It is essential to recall what you mean by $\mathbb{H}$, in particular, as I said, if (t,x,y) is meant to be equivalent to $(1,x/t,y/t)$. In this case, it is not usual to call it "hyperbolic", it is the projective space $\mathbb{RP}^2$.